# Remove just the alphabet characters from a string

Tags: python, regex

In python,

I have string like

```
"dsafsadf_afasa_2.2.14_43.33_dsfd"
```

I need to get just

```
"2.2.14_43.33"
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Removing just the alphabet would leave - `__2.2.14_43.33_` - for your example , is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to remove all alphabets and all the underscores except if the undercore is present inbetween digits,.

```
>>> s = "dsafsadf_afasa_2.2.14_43.33_dsfd"
>>> re.sub(r'[a-z]|(?<=\D)_(?=\d)|(?<=\d)_(?=\D)|(?<=\D)_(?=\D)|^_+|_+$', '', s)
'2.2.14_43.33'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.translate if you just want to remove the letters:

```
s = "dsafsadf_afasa_2.2.14_43.33_dsfd"


from string import ascii_letters
print(s.translate(None,ascii_letters))
```

which outputs:

```
__2.2.14_43.33_
```

For python3:

```
from string import ascii_letters
print(s.translate({ord(ch):"" for ch in ascii_letters}))
```

If you really want to remove underscores from the end use strip:

```
s = "dsafsadf_afasa_2.2.14_43.33_dsfd"

from string import ascii_letters

print(s.translate(None,ascii_letters).strip("_"))
```

Output:

```
2.2.14_43.33
```

Comment: Is this answer for some other question? I ran this and got - `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` . Then atfter I ran this after removing the `None` , I got - `dsafsadf_afasa_YUYUX4_4ZUZZ_dsfd` . If this is only for some spcific python version I would advice to specify that in the answer . (It ran for me only in Python 2.x , did not work in Python 3.x)

Comment: @AnandSKumar, then you  must be doing it wrong or using python3

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a `re.findall`.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\d+(?:[\W_]\d+)*')
test_str = "dsafsadf_afasa_2.2.14_43.33_dsfd"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hF1wE3/2